# How to make child-div get equal height of its parent without using flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I am trying to solve this problem in many different ways and it is not working.

I have a row of 2 columns. The first column has text that will receive dynamic text. The other column has an image that must adapt its size responsively, no matter the text-content height is. The text column is leading the height of the row-parent div, so, my image-parent div must get the 100% height of that. Is there any solution available that does not use flex-box or JS? I am trying to avoid using flexbox/JS in this case.

[This is the result at the moment:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN9ti.png)

The parent div is high because of a Text that is beside the image on the same row.

PS: I put a height of 100px on the image just to show you. I know I can't use a fix height. How do I make that div that contains the background-image follow the height of the parent-row div independently of the amount of content (text) that it has?

Thank you so much in advance!

Here's my HTML:

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 no-padding">
              <div class="img-parent"></div>
            </div><!-- ./col-xs-12 -->

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 text-parent">
              <h2>My Title</h2>
              <h3>My subtitle</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, totam ducimus! Aspernatur porro, accusantium consequatur neque id praesentium ipsum consequuntur cum? Voluptates minus ad repellendus aspernatur, rem modi dolor cum.</p>

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error culpa facere quae pariatur nam dolorem ab est perferendis! Ipsa id aut nesciunt sit ea fugiat saepe sequi quisquam labore quae.</p>
            </div><!-- ./text-parent -->
          </div><!-- ./row -->
        </div><!-- ./container -->
      </section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.text-parent{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  padding:30px;
}

.text-parent h2,
.text-parent h3{
  font-weight:600;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.text-parent h2{
  font-size: 45px;
}

.text-parent h3{
  max-width:560px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#ed1c24;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

.text-parent p{
  max-width:500px;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:20px;
  text-align:justify;
}

.row{
  border:3px solid green;
}

.no-padding{
  padding:0;
}

.img-parent{
  height:100px; /*just to show a little part of the image*/
  background-image:url("https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Natural-Dog-Law-2-To-dogs%2C-energy-is-everything.jpg?itok=Z-ujUOUr");

  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Why not use flexbox?

Comment: I think flexbox will break the bootstrap 3 css. I am avoiding to use it. Also trying to figure out an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

**html**

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 no-padding"></div>
            <!-- ./col-xs-12 -->

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 text-parent">
                <h2>My Title</h2>
                <h3>My subtitle</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, totam ducimus! Aspernatur porro, accusantium consequatur neque id praesentium ipsum consequuntur cum? Voluptates minus ad repellendus aspernatur, rem modi dolor cum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error culpa facere quae pariatur nam dolorem ab est perferendis! Ipsa id aut nesciunt sit ea fugiat saepe sequi quisquam labore quae.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- ./text-parent --> 
        </div>
        <!-- ./row --> 
    </div>
    <!-- ./container --> 
</section>
```

**css**

```
.text-parent h3 {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text-parent h2 {
    font-size: 45px;
}
.text-parent h3 {
    max-width: 560px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ed1c24;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.text-parent p {
    max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.row {
    border: 3px solid green;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
.no-padding {
    background-image: url("https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Natural-Dog-Law-2-To-dogs%2C-energy-is-everything.jpg?itok=Z-ujUOUr");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row > div {
        display: block;
    }
    .no-padding {
        padding: 25% 0;
    }
    .row {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

image-size, image-position and image-repeat are not valid CSS properties, you mean background-size, background-position and background-repeat.

Also, you don't need a separate bootstrap row for that, just set it as background for your "text" row and it'll work fine.

```css
.text-parent{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  padding:30px;
}

.text-parent h2,
.text-parent h3{
  font-weight:600;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.text-parent h2{
  font-size: 45px;
}

.text-parent h3{
  max-width:560px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#ed1c24;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

.text-parent p{
  max-width:500px;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:20px;
  text-align:justify;
}

.row{
  border:3px solid green;
}

.no-padding{
  padding:0;
}

.img-parent{
  background-image:url("https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Natural-Dog-Law-2-To-dogs%2C-energy-is-everything.jpg?itok=Z-ujUOUr");

  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 text-parent img-parent"><!-- ADDED img-parent class -->
              <h2>My Title</h2>
              <h3>My subtitle</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, totam ducimus! Aspernatur porro, accusantium consequatur neque id praesentium ipsum consequuntur cum? Voluptates minus ad repellendus aspernatur, rem modi dolor cum.</p>

              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error culpa facere quae pariatur nam dolorem ab est perferendis! Ipsa id aut nesciunt sit ea fugiat saepe sequi quisquam labore quae.</p>
            </div><!-- ./text-parent -->
          </div><!-- ./row -->
        </div><!-- ./container -->
      </section>
```

Comment: You are right, I was writing the example quickly and confused the property names. However, I am not trying to put the image as a background for the text. What I am trying to do is put it on the right side of the text. Heres the link for the codepen: https://codepen.io/jorgemonte/pen/VQVPYd

Answer (score 0):

First, image-size、image-position and image-repeat should be background-size、background-position and background-repeat。

Now, you can change '.img-parent' to:

```
.img-parent {
  height: 100%;
  background:url("https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Natural-Dog-Law-2-To-dogs%2C-energy-is-everything.jpg?itok=Z-ujUOUr") no-repeat center / cover;
}
```